# String matching in if statement not working

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to Python, but I can't quite figure out what is wrong with my code.

I have a csv file, and, I am trying to remove rows based on the content of said row. I have used the csv module to make a list of lists, with each list in the list being a row.

This first part works as I expect.  It goes through all of the rows of data, and if the string match is true, it ignores the row and prints the statement in the code.  If false, it takes that row and appends it to a new list called 'inactive_list'.

```
print('Inactive Pass\n')
inactive_list.insert(0, data[0])
for row in range(1, len(data)):
    if not 'Active' in data[row][9]:
        print('Removed row #' + str(row) + '\n' + str(data[row]) +'\n')
    else:
        inactive_list.append(data[row])
print(inactive_list)
```

In the same function, I have a second for loop as shown below:

```
print('\n\n\nDemo Pass')
for row in range(1, len(inactive_list)):
    if 'demo' or 'demo'.upper() or 'demo'.title() in inactive_list[row][0]:
        print('Removed row #' + str(row) + '\n' + str(data[row]) +'\n')
    else:
        demo_list.append(data[row])
print(demo_list)
```

This loop is very similar to the one above, with the difference that I am trying to match "demo", "Demo" or "DEMO" at index 0 of each list in the list - and if it matches to do the same as the first loop.  Essentially appending the rows that do NOT match, to a new list.

This second loop, just matches every row no matter what is in index 0 of each list.

I am very green at programming, so my apologies if this is a bit basic.

Comment: I don't really know python but I would try `if 'demo in inactive_list[row][0] or 'demo'.upper in inactive_list[row][0] or  'demo'.title() in inactive_list[row][0]:` I suspect that the statement `if 'demo'` actually evaluates to `if 'demo' != None` You are therefore asking `if 'demo' != None or 'demo'.upper() != None or 'demo'.title() in inactive_list[row][0]:` Anyone know the language and can confirm this?

Comment: yes your logic is correct @SamM

Comment: could also use the built-in [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function for a maybe easier to understand syntax `if any('demo' or 'demo'.upper() or 'demo'.title() in inactive_list[row][0]):`, but SamM's logic suggests the straightforward fix

Comment: @SamM has hit the nail on the head, and now it works.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
if 'demo' or 'demo'.upper() or 'demo'.title() in inactive_list[row][0]:
```

to

```
if inactive_list[row][0] in ('demo', 'demo'.upper(), 'demo'.title()):
```